# Do attacks that hit multiple enemies (or one enemy multiple times) generate multiple on-hit triggers?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Wizard's skill Electrocute is a bolt of chain lightning, which (without runes) hits one target, and can jump to two additional targets. There are numerous other skills that can hit multiple enemies - the Wizard's Shock Pulse, the Wizard's Disintegrate, and the Demon Hunter's Chakram are more examples. Also, some attacks hit the same enemy multiple times on a single use of the skill.

Does each "injuring" of an enemy generate an on-hit effect? How do multiple-hit or multiple-opponent-hit skills interact with on-hit effects like chance to stun, life on hit, and class resource generation?

Comment: The percentage you get of your life on hit varies based on the skill, but yeah, it triggers for each enemy hit. For example, for barbarian skills, see [this chart](http://i.imgur.com/ewTt0.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For attacks that hit multiple enemies, Yes.

I haven't explicitly tested all on-hit effects. I will update this answer as I do.

**Life on hit:** Confirmed. With a +2 life on hit weapon equipped, I often saw healing popups of +6, +8, +10, etc while using area attacks that hit multiple targets.

**Chance on hit to fear:** Confirmed. Using [Deadly Reach](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/deadly-reach) I saw two enemies get feared and run away.