# Does the "Life on Hit" affix work on channeled / DoT wizard spells?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “on hit” effects work with channeled / DoT skills?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71974/how-do-on-hit-effects-work-with-channeled-dot-skills)

I know for melee "Life on Hit" is a great affix, but for a wizard that only casts ray of frost / hydra / blizzard is it worth investing on weapon that has "Life on Hit" on it?

Thanks.

Comment: even if it does, it would just have a really low modifier, so even if you have each hit adds 100 health, it might only add 10 health per tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, channelled spells do cause the "Gain life on hit" effect to proc. All abilities in the game have a coefficient which is applied to this effect. This coefficient is extremely low for channelled spells to offset the ability to hit several times per second, so each hit only heals a very small amount. Yes, it can be useful still, but no more so than normal casts; the fact you are hitting constantly won't make you overpowered.